# Set OData navigation properties using Fluent Api

Tags: c#, navigation-properties, ef-fluent-api, asp.net-web-api-odata

Given a **Web Api 2.2** project using **OData 4**, I'm using entities from a third shared assembly and I would like to configure some entities specifically for the api.

For instance: one of the shared entities **SharedEntityA** contains a field **BinaryValue** which I don't want to be *navigable*, *sortable*, *filterable*, etc.

The problem is I can't change the shared assembly and therefore I can't use attributes for it, like:

```cs
[Unsortable]
[NonFilterable]
[NotNavigable]
public byte[] BinaryValue { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to config that in my api project using **Fluent Api**?

I'm looking for something like this in App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs:

```cs
private static IEdmModel CreateEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<SharedEntityA>();

    // This is not working
    builder.Entity<SharedEntityA>()
        .property(e => e.BinaryValue)
        .IsNotSortable()
        .IsNotFilterable()
        .IsNotNavigable();
}
```

The example throws compile error

> PrimitivePropertyConfiguration does not contain a definition for IsNotSortable

Comment: Got it working after replacing all _usings_ `System.Web.Http.OData.*` with `System.Web.OData.*`